# Defining arrow function in react function-based component's return statement performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any performance penalty for defining arrow functions in React function-based component's return statement rather than in the body of the component? For example, which is better and why, this:

```js
const Test = () => {
  const [isPopupOpen, setPopupOpen] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <Popup handleClose={() => setPopupOpen(false)}>Anything</Popup>
  )
}
```

VS

```js
const Test = () => {
  const [isPopupOpen, setPopupOpen] = React.useState(false);

  // we use a hook so we cannot move it out of the component entirely
  const closePopup = () => setPopupOpen(false)

  return (
    <Popup handleClose={closePopup}>Anything</Popup>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both do exactly the same thing other than that the second one creates a binding within the function's execution context (loosely, a "variable") while the first doesn't. That's not going to impact your performance in any noticeable way.

Answer (score 1):

No it won't effect any performance impact over the application. Provided the second one will help you implement any business logic before updating the state. Infact you can do it with the first one also, but for the sake of readability in case you want some extra logic second one will be preferred. Otherwise for a direct narrow implementation, you're good to go with the first one.